# Django: Save html entries in mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to follow this open source project to learn more about Django and crispy.
[For that I try to extend this open source project](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html)

I downloaded the project from GitHub and got it running :). However, the models.py is missing and I thought I'll try to add it, and push the html form data into my local mysql db. So basically I'm trying to extend that existing code. I was able to add the models.py and create the table in mysql.

**Issue: If I press the submit button, no data appears in mysql. What I think I figured out is, I need some "save()" command. But where?
I also get this error: "POST /form/4/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0"**

I found postings on google about codlins in forms.py and view.py. But either it did not resolve it or cause error. Any ideas how to overcome this?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from mysite.core.choice import STATES

class Address(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=STATES, blank=True)
    check_me_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py --> Also with comments about what I changed vs. the original

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Submit, Row, Column, Field
from .choice import STATES
from .models import Address

class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    Model = Address ####new added by me
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    address_1 = forms.CharField(label='Address', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '1234 Main St'}))
    address_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Apartment, studio, or floor'}))
    city = forms.CharField()
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATES)
    zip_code = forms.CharField(label='Zip')
    check_me_out = forms.BooleanField(required=False)


class CrispyAddressForm(AddressForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post' ##### new added by me
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Sign in')) ##### new added by me
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('email', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('password', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'address_1',
            'address_2',
            Row(
                Column('city', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('state', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                Column('zip_code', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'check_me_out',
            #Submit('submit', 'Sign in') ##### originally in there but commented out by me
        )


class CustomCheckbox(Field):
    template = 'custom_checkbox.html'

class CustomFieldForm(AddressForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('email', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('password', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'address_1',
            'address_2',
            Row(
                Column('city', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('state', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                Column('zip_code', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            CustomCheckbox('check_me_out'),
            Submit('submit', 'Sign in')
        )
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .forms import AddressForm, CrispyAddressForm, CustomFieldForm


class AddressFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AddressForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')


class CrispyAddressFormView(FormView):
     form_class = CrispyAddressForm
     success_url = reverse_lazy('success')
     template_name = 'crispy_form.html'

class CustomFieldFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomFieldForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')
    template_name = 'crispy_form.html'


class SuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'success.html'
```

please let me know if you want to see more code like the html or so.

Comment: Instead of forms.Form use [`forms.ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). and instead of FormView use [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView)

Comment: This helped for sure

Answer (score 0):

ok that works @Abdul Aziz Barkat

but only if I add

```
class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'check_me_out')
```

But now my definitions from
**class AddressForm(forms.Form)**
are gone.
How can I get them back

Comment: You can simply keep your field definitions in the class. It would work properly.

Comment: Keep the block **and** the Meta class. Also why are you posting multiple answers instead of editing your answer. Why are you posting a **question** as an answer? Also remove that model you had written in your first (outside the meta, what would the form do with that attribute anyway?)

Comment: i tried again and the and command worked. as to the answers, I simply didn't know. Will  consider it going forward